# How many different sudoku puzzles are there?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, sudoku

The answer: 6, 670, 903, 752, 021, 072, 936, 960, according to this site:

https://www.technologyreview.com/2012/01/06/188520/mathematicians-solve-minimum-sudoku-problem/

I have tried to get this number using direct methods but basically I have found the question too hard. There are too many possibilities, but I am likely missing some strategic ways to solve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You should be more precise about when two give sudokus are different. For example given some sudokus you can use a rotation to get a new one. Or another way is just renaming the 1 into 2 and vice versa

Comment: So as in Wikipedia stand there are actually  5,472,730,538 different sudokus (taken symmetries in account)

Comment: If you care that it is solvable: [How many Sudoku puzzles are there with at least one solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/856478/318073); If you care that it has a unique solution: [How many different “tight” sudoku puzzles are there?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3686495/318073).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.afjarvis.staff.shef.ac.uk/sudoku/sudoku.pdf ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Beat me to it (again)

Comment: Super. Thanks Chris.

Comment: Link doesn't redirect to the pdf, & the user's last seen is more than 8 years ago!

Comment: Yes, that's the main reason why "link-only" answers are considered poor: When I tried the link today I got "https://afjarvis.sites.sheffield.ac.uk/", showing "*LaTeX in open captions for MP4 videos*".

Answer (score 0):

Try [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku#Enumerating_Sudoku_solutions) for an introduction and overview and additional references.

Comment: Somehow I'm missing the explanation for the bug number there. I had thought about it myself, and thought like this: For the first row there are 9! possibilities, and for the second row there are 8! possibilities (each column has one possibility less). Then by induction I would get "9! * 8! * 7! *6! * 5! *4! *3! *2! *1!", or near 1.83 * 10^21, but the official number is higher.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be (9!)squared X 9
The 9 is from the 9 different puzzles with the center number changed.
Then you would have to subtract all the puzzles with 0 thru 7 solved numbers(if you had the 8th solved, the empty spaces would be the next solved number and the puzzle)

Answer (score -2):

Based on the equation (9!^2(9)), the number of possible sudoku puzzles is exactly 1,185,137,049,600.