# How many different "tight" sudoku puzzles are there?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, sudoku

[How many different sudoku puzzles are there?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275422/how-many-different-sudoku-puzzles-are-there) posted a similar question and Chris Eagle's answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/275425/26632 points to http://www.afjarvis.staff.shef.ac.uk/sudoku/sudoku.pdf saying that there are $6,670,903,752, 021,072,936,960$ different grids.

However, *grid* is not *puzzle*:

- a grid is a *final* status, with all 81 cells known; where a puzzle is the *initial* status, some difficult sudoku puzzles starts with only 17 or 18 cells given.
- for a given *grid*, masking different cells will start a different *puzzle*.
- a *puzzle* shall have but only 1 solution, ie. 1 *grid*. There shall be no ambiguity, i.e. a puzzle shall not have multiple solutions.
- to be neat, we prefer to start with a *tight* puzzle, i.e., the puzzle provides necessary information but no more, or, masking any of the numbers provided will lead to ambiguity.

So, how many sudoku *tight* puzzles are there? As explained above, $6,670,903,752, 021,072,936,960$ is the answer only for grid but not for puzzle count.

If this is too difficult, how many $4\times 4$ sudoku *tight* puzzles are there?

Comment: According to the [article](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00641955) referenced at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku#Mathematics_of_Sudoku): For $9\times 9$ this long-standing mathematical problem has not been solved, but statistical simulations (using several months of $3$ GHz CPU time) indicate that on average about $4.67\,10^{15}$ tight puzzles can be made from each grid; in other words, there are about $3.10\,10^{37}$ different tight puzzles, and about $2.55\,10^{25}$ tight puzzles that are non-isomorphic.